# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home1/gcc/public_html/university/core/init.php on line 22

Tags: php

Run the code in local host wamp, but when i uploaded to the server i got this error. Below is my code

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db'=> 'database name'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token',
        'secure' => rand(1000, 9999)
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {            // error here
    require_once 'classes/' .$class. '.php';
});
```

Comment: Anonymous functions only work from PHP 5.3 onwards.

Comment: What is your PHP version ?

Comment: @user3000085 So you need to upgrade your PHP or rewrite script to not use anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems because you are running on an old PHP version (older than PHP 5.3), anonymous function are seen as syntax errors. PHP implements callbacks as string. You can define the function normally, and pass a name of the function instead.

```
function custom_autoloader($class) {
    // your code..
}

spl_autoload_register('custom_autoloader');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP version is not supporting anonymous function. You need at least 5.3.0

You can check your current version eg. using `phpinfo()`.

Comment: According to the manual, `(PHP 5 >= 5.1.2)`

Comment: @webnoob According to tests, 5.3.0+ :) Eg. in 5.2.10 anonymous functions will produce `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`.

Comment: How odd, what is the world coming to if we can't rely on the manual!! :)

Comment: @webnoob Check my comment under your post ;)

Comment: Yeah, saw it thanks and removed the post. Makes more sense than cluttering with wrong information :) Thanks.